# foreach control structure in php for arrays

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, iteration

```
$myarray = array("Jim", "Jane", "Tom");
foreach($myarray as $value)
{
    $a = 0;
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
```

Outputs a 000.
Why is the $a variable not incremented by 1 on each iteration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

move $a out side of the loop, since $a is always declared as 0

```
$a = 0;
$myarray = array("Jim", "Jane", "Tom");
foreach($myarray as $value)
{
    echo $a;
    $a++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Class's answer covers the immediate problem, but it may also be useful for you to be aware that you can take a simpler approach to the indexing in the first place, like:

```
$myarray = array("Jim", "Jane", "Tom");
foreach(array_keys($myarray) as $i)
{
    echo $i;
    echo $myarray[$i];
}
```